# Magento - Please specify the product required option(s)

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

There is a problem with my Magento store. When I try to add products variable product into the cart it says please specify the product required option(s) but I have already selected the options. But when I try to add simple products then it is added successfully. I want to know what is the problem. I have previously hosted this website on AWS and now migrated this to SiteGround. Is this server migration cause some problem. I use the same URL.

Comment: check there is any JS error or not. Options value not posted when you click addToCart.

Comment: Sir where can I find any JS error. This is not an issue before migration to siteground.